# How can I change the style of two-cells?

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

How can I change the style of a two-cell? Take the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix@C+1pc{C \rtwocell<4>  & D}$

\end{document}
```

There will be a downward double arrow in the middle of the diagram. How can I change its style? Say, to be a zigzag arrow. What I mean is, if it was a normal arrow in xypic, I would change its style like this: `\ar@{~}[d]`.

Comment: Would you be willing to use another package such as the more modern and versatile [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arrow is changed via `\arrowobject`.  By default this is `\dir{=>}` where `=>` is defined in `xy2cell.tex` as

```
\newdir{=>}{!/5pt/\dir{=}!/2.5pt/\dir{=}*!/-5pt/\dir2{>}}
```

You can make a squiggly arrow with something like

```
\newdir{~>}{!/2.5pt/\dir{~}*!/-5pt/\dir2{>}}
```

and use this as

```
$\arrowobject{\dir{~>}}\xymatrix@C+1pc{C \rtwocell<4>  & D}$
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells

\newdir{~>}{!/2.5pt/\dir{~}*!/-5pt/\dir2{>}}

\begin{document}

$\arrowobject{\dir{~>}}\xymatrix@C+1pc{C \rtwocell<4>  & D}$

\end{document}
```

Further details are in the reference manual `xyrefer.pdf` obtainable as `texdoc xyrefer`

For a connection without an arrowhead you can use one of

[image: Second sample]

```
$\arrowobject{\dir{~}}\xymatrix@C+1pc{C \rtwocell<4>  & D}$

\newdir{l~}{!/3.5pt/\dir{~}*!/-3.5pt/\dir{~}}
$\arrowobject{\dir{l~}}\xymatrix@C+1pc{C \rtwocell<4>  & D}$
```

The `\newdir` is a composite object built up of units separated by `*`.  A unit `!/3.5t/\dir{~}` takes the tip `~` and slides it `3.5pt` (back) along the path.

Comment: How can I get it not to have a tip? Like it would result if I used `\ar@{~}` in an `xymatrix` environment. Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoStonek I have updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question asks specifically about `2cell`, but this is how you'd do it using the more modern [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package; the squiggly line was produced using a `snake` decoration from the `decorations.pathmorphing` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{no tip/.style={arrows=-}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
C \ar[r, bend left=50, ""{name=U, below}]
\ar[r, bend right=50, ""{name=D}]
& D
\ar[decorate, decoration={snake},from=U, to=D,no tip]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you for your answer. However, I'd prefer to stick to `xypic` , being used to the syntax and all...

Comment: @BrunoStonek Of course, I understand.